# UML for a business rules

Tags: uml

I want to create a class diagram UML for a part or bundle of my wbesite.  This part contains three sub-parts :

1. Job  : I want to show a list of jobs by date (title, date of job, location, deadline)
2. When I click on a job in list, I hope to have details of the job (title, description...)
3. Administration of list of jobs (delete, create, edit...)

I can imagine the template of view to create it but I hope to create a class diagram UML for Business Rules (class abstract,method,object...) to use after I create my code.

I'm not very professional in UML.  Can someone give me an exepmle of graph or schema to create it, a prediction for method and object to use it in template.

Comment: If I understand right, you want to model dynamic behaviour with a static model. I only know UML, not symfony. But if somebody speaks about business rules, I first think about Activity-Diagrams. Do you want to model behaviour or static artifacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from some of my old college coursework. It may be of some use. Sorry if I can't help you further as I too am starting out professionally.

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oe9zfwt18g3t1st/ClassDiagram.png]

Comment: Ok I see,your example is very helpful but I need a solution about my example or my problem!!

Comment: I am not doing your work for you. I just thought that this would have been a decent guide, for future reference.

Comment: Im not seaching for someone to do my work,but I need just and idea o start but with my axample and a solution for my problem